# Adding a tax_query to a WP_Query Object

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

Is it possible to modify a `WP_Query` object to add a `tax_query`?

That is -- I'm able to add a `tax_query` when instantiating a `WP_Query` object

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
                'post-format-link',
            ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
));
```

The above query only returns posts with a link format.

However, if I have an already instantiated `WP_Query` object, I'm not able to *set* a `tax_query`.  If I try it like this

```
$q = new WP_Query(['post_type'=>'post']);
$q->set('tax_query', array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array(
            'post-format-link',
        ),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
));
```

My query returns all post types, not just link posts.

Is this possible to do?  If so, am I using `set` wrong, or do tax queries need to be set differently?

If it helps, the larger context is I'm trying to change a query object in the `pre_get_posts` action-hook. I've been able to use the `pre_get_posts` hook to add a category filter to a query

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
        if(!$query->is_main_query() || is_admin() || !is_front_page()) {
            return;
        }
        $term = get_category_by_slug('my-slug');
        if(!$term || !is_numeric($term->term_id)) {
            return;
        }
        $query->set('category__not_in', $term->term_id);
    });
```

With the above in place my front page omits posts with the `my-slug` category.

However, if I try a similar thing with a `tax_query`, the front page is not restricted to link posts.  The following

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
        if(!$query->is_main_query() || is_admin() || !is_front_page()) {
            return;
        }
        // per an answer below, I've tried things both with and without
        // this next line and have not had luck in getting my tax_query 
        // to apply to the WP_Query
        // $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query', [] );        
        
        $query->set('tax_query',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array(
                    'post-format-link',
                ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        );
    });
```

has no effect on the global query for the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instantiate `WP_Query` with arguments, as in your second example, then the query is performed right away, and setting new arguments will not change the results.

```
$q = new WP_Query( [ 'post_type' => 'post' ] );

$q->set( 'tax_query', [] ); // Too late.
```

If you instantiate `WP_Query` without arguments, like this:

```
$q = new WP_Query();
```

Then the query is not performed until `$q->get_posts()` is run. This means that you can set query vars after the object is created:

```
$q = new WP_Query();

$q->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
$q->set( 'tax_query', [] );

$q->get_posts();

while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    // etc..
}
```

There's nothing special about `tax_query` when it comes to setting arguments like this.

The `pre_get_posts` hook is fired inside `WP_Query::get_posts()`, before the query itself is performed, so in that hook there's no reason you can't set `tax_query`:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', [] );
    }
);
```

The one thing that might trip you up is that any given query might already have a `tax_query`, and by setting it yourself you could be removing that original query. The way around this is to retrieve the original query, and then add yours.

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query', [] ); // Make sure we have an array as the default.

        $new_tax_query = [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'terms'    => [ 'post-format-link' ],
            ],
            $tax_query,
        ];

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $new_tax_query );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob -- I learned things -- in particular that creating a WP_Query object with/without args can affect when the actual query runs.  After taking your post into consideration and re-looking at my own code, the problem is/was that the `tax_query` value I was setting was not correctly formatted.  I was missing an outer array. I've updated the question to make that clearer for the next person to stumble across this.  Thanks again for your help.